# How can you get a ComboBox child of a DataGridView to process all keys, including "."?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the same problem as described in the posts listed below.   That is, certain keys don't work at all when I type them into my combobox until I first hit the spacebar.  One of the keys is ".", but another is the letter "Q", and there are others: "$", "%".

http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=659716&SiteID=1
http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2909173&SiteID=1&pageid=0
http://bytes.com/forum/thread548399.html

I've tried a lot of things so far.  My latest failure was based on the theory that maybe the DataGridView was using WIN32 API wndproc subclassing to intercept messages, so I wrote logic to save the old wndproc and restore it after adding it to the DataGridView's control collection.   That didn't work.

Messina - thanks for reminding me about Spy++.     For the letter "A", the edit window sends an EN_UPDATE to its combobox parent.   But, not for the "Q".   That's so strange.

I have convinced myself that the DataGridView is not subclassing the combo and the edit, because I check the address of the wndprocs just after creation and before adding them to the grid's collection, and then later when I paint.    Unless the grid installs some sort of global hooks..

I'm thinkin, maybe I can subclass the edit control, and then send the notification to the combobox the way I see the edit control doing here?

EDIT:  More info here.   Windows messages from grid, combobox, and edit control, from Spy++:

HWNDs:
122064e < grid
010d0674 < combobox
01360696 < combox's edit control

```
<01402> 01360696 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<01403> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01404> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01405> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01406> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01407> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01408> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01409> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01410> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01411> 01360696 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'0061' (97) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<01412> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01413> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01414> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01415> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS

<01416> 010D0674 S WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:EN_UPDATE wID:1001 hwndCtl:01360696  <<< edit control sends to combobox

<01417> 010D0674 S message:0x2111 [User-defined:WM_USER+7441] wParam:00060674 lParam:010D0674    What do these do?
<01418> 010D0674 R message:0x2111 [User-defined:WM_USER+7441] lResult:00000000

<01419> 010D0674 R WM_COMMAND
<01420> 010D0674 S WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hdcEdit:C7011AA6 hwndEdit:01360696
<01421> 010D0674 R WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hBrush:F0103EB0

<01422> 010D0674 S WM_COMMAND wNotifyCode:EN_CHANGE wID:1001 hwndCtl:01360696  << edit control sends to combobox

<01423> 010D0674 S message:0x2111 [User-defined:WM_USER+7441] wParam:00050674 lParam:010D0674

<01424> 0122064E S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000   <<< grid is told to paint
<01425> 0122064E S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:94011D4E
<01426> 0122064E R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<01427> 0122064E S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01428> 0122064E R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:0
<01429> 0122064E S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:2 lpszText:0012D0C0
<01430> 0122064E R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:0 lpszText:0012D0C0 ("")
<01431> 0122064E S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01432> 0122064E R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:0
<01433> 0122064E S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:2 lpszText:0012D0C0
<01434> 0122064E R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:0 lpszText:0012D0C0 ("")
<01435> 010D0674 S WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING lpwp:0012D4B0
<01436> 010D0674 R WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
<01437> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01438> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01439> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01440> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01441> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01442> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01443> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012CC44
<01444> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012BE64
<01445> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012BE64 ("a")
<01446> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012CC44 ("a")
<01447> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01448> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01449> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01450> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01451> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01452> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01453> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012CC44
<01454> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012BE64
<01455> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012BE64 ("a")
<01456> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012CC44 ("a")
<01457> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01458> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01531> 0122064E R WM_PAINT
<01532> 010D0674 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000
<01533> 010D0674 S WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
<01534> 010D0674 R WM_NCPAINT
<01535> 010D0674 S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:0F0141ED
<01536> 010D0674 R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<01537> 0122064E S WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hdcEdit:840137F1 hwndEdit:010D0674
<01538> 0122064E R WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hBrush:F0103EB0
<01539> 010D0674 R WM_PAINT
<01540> 01360696 S WM_PAINT hdc:00000000
<01541> 01360696 S WM_NCPAINT hrgn:00000001
<01542> 01360696 R WM_NCPAINT
<01543> 01360696 S WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:C7011AA6
<01544> 01360696 R WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
<01545> 010D0674 S WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hdcEdit:870137F1 hwndEdit:01360696
<01546> 010D0674 R WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hBrush:F0103EB0
<01547> 010D0674 S WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hdcEdit:870137F1 hwndEdit:01360696
<01548> 010D0674 R WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hBrush:F0103EB0
<01549> 01360696 R WM_PAINT
<01555> 0122064E S WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hdcEdit:8A0137F1 hwndEdit:010306AC
<01556> 0122064E R WM_CTLCOLOREDIT hBrush:78103C5B
<01568> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01569> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01570> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01571> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01572> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01573> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01574> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012D7A4
<01575> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012C9C4
<01576> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012C9C4 ("a")
<01577> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012D7A4 ("a")
<01578> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01579> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01580> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01581> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01582> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01583> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01584> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012D6E0
<01585> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012C900
<01586> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012C900 ("a")
<01587> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012D6E0 ("a")
<01588> 010D0674 S CB_GETCURSEL
<01589> 010D0674 R CB_GETCURSEL index:CB_ERR
<01590> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01591> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01592> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01593> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01594> 010D0674 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012D6E0
<01595> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012C900
<01596> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012C900 ("a")
<01597> 010D0674 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012D6E0 ("a")
<01598> 010D0674 R message:0x2111 [User-defined:WM_USER+7441] lResult:00000000
<01599> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
<01600> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXTLENGTH cch:2
<01601> 01360696 S WM_GETTEXT cchTextMax:6 lpszText:0012DF8C
<01602> 01360696 R WM_GETTEXT cchCopied:2 lpszText:0012DF8C ("a")
<01603> 010D0674 R WM_COMMAND
<01604> 01360696 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

Letter q

```
<01625> 01360696 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'Q' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:10 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<01626> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01627> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01628> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01629> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01630> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01631> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01632> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01633> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01634> 01360696 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'0071' (113) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:10 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<01635> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01636> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01637> 010D0674 S WM_GETDLGCODE
<01638> 010D0674 R WM_GETDLGCODE fuDlgCode:DLGC_WANTARROWS | DLGC_WANTCHARS
<01640> 01360696 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'Q' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:10 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

Comment: I tried the example from the bytes.com forum, and it didn't work for me. I'd be happy to give some code a spin if you have repro steps.

Comment: I came here looking for the meaing of `S message:0x2111 [User-defined:WM_USER+7441]` but anyway I bet I can guess what is going on. The keys you are missing are already mapped. Perhaps Ctrl+Q = quit. The combox isn't handling hotkeys well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By any chance, have you already solved your problem?

I have the same problem as yours, my custom control for DataGridView cannot receive letter Q, period, dollar, single quote, percent, etc.

I was able to solve the problem by changing the "switch .. default: return false" to "switch .. default: return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey"

I guess the pattern code from Microsoft for making your own usercontrol for datagridview is not optimal.  This is the pattern code from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/7tas5c80(vs.80).aspx

```
public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
    Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
{
    // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
    switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.Home:
        case Keys.End:
        case Keys.PageDown:
        case Keys.PageUp:
            return true;
        default:
            return false; // I changed this to: return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey.  My usercontrol can now receive Q, period, dollar, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not solved the problem.  I've tried your solution and that's not working for me, and after thinking about it, I'm not surprised.  I'm using the combobox in the header, not a regular cell.  I don't think my grid knows enough about my combobox to discover and use its IDataGridViewEditingControl interface.   I mean, I think I have more problems than just this problem.  I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to my question.   In the Combobox I handle the KeyDown, TextChanged, and KeyUp events, which fire in that order.  If I go from KeyDown to KeyUp with TextChanged skipped, I check whether the character was a Keys.Q or Keys.OemPeriod.  (I'm not sure it's safe to others, like shift/D1, shift/D2, etc...).    If it's one of those keys, I change the combobox text myself.

But that's not enough, because merely changing the text sets the cursor in the edit control (that belongs to the combobox) to the start of the text.   So, to fix that,  I use FindWindowEx to get the handle of the edit control, then send it a EM_SETSEL to reset the cursor to the end of the word.